# playwright using indexedDB

Tags: javascript, playwright

is it possible to somehow interact with indexeddb ?

I want to test UI using test data in indexeddb.

I am using the code from the documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBFactory and I get the error

```
 indexedDB is not defined 
window is not defined
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use `page.evaluate` to execute JavaScript inside your page: https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-evaluate

```js
// @ts-check
const playwright = require('playwright');

(async () => {
  // Try to add 'firefox' to the list ↓
  for (const browserType of [playwright.chromium, playwright.firefox, playwright.webkit]) {
    const browser = await browserType.launch();
    const context = await browser.newContext();
    const page = await context.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://example.org/');
    console.log(await page.evaluate(() => {
      return typeof window.indexedDB
    }));
    await browser.close();
  }
})();
```

Make sure to pass any values which you want to share from Node.js with the browser as a second argument, see here: https://playwright.dev/docs/next/evaluating